# A series involving factorials

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

The question concerns this function $$f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(4n)!}{(2n)!n!}x^n$$ Do you know if it has any familiar representation?

My attempts: I was initially led astray by its resemblance to

$$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n (2n)!}{4^n (n!)^2} x^n = (1 + x)^{-1/2}$$

but it didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: I check at WolframAlpha: the sum diverges at any positive $x$

Comment: they meant $$f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(4n)!}{(2n)!(n!)^2}x^n$$  which has a nonzero radius of convergence

Answer (score 3):

According to sequence $A349468$ in $OEIS$
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(4n)!}{(2n)!\,n!}x^n$$ is the exponential generating function of $$\frac{2 }{\pi  \sqrt{8 \sqrt{x}+1}}K\left(\frac{16 \sqrt{x}}{1+8 \sqrt{x}}\right)$$ where $K(.)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

As you properly almost guessed , they are related to the coefficients of  the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}$